# how to read an xml node text with spaces using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I want to read the text of an XML node from my config file. For this I have used Xpath to read the values. One of the config values is having the space between it's conetents, so when I am reading that it's just returning the value till the white space.
My config filename and content as below
config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpsConfig>
    <Tenant>mytenant_az1</Tenant>
    <Client>XYZ</Client>
    <ReviewID>a123456</ReviewID>
    <ReferenceID>ARTL_Is Correction_Rewind_Report</ReferenceID>
<OpsConfig>
```

I am successfully able to read the tag values except for the tag **ReferenceID**. 
Below is the code:

```
$configFile = "config.xml"
[xml]$confXml = Get-Content $configFile
$refIds = $confXml | Select-XML -XPath "//OpsConfig/ReferenceID"
Write-Host $refIds
```

The variable $refIds just returns "ARTL_Is". It's skipping the content after the space. I tried by appending the hexa value of space but still didn't return the whole value "ARTL_Is Correction_Rewind_Report".

Comment: Your xml has an error in the closing tag; missing `/`. have not edited as this may be related to your issue. For me, I am getting the full string "ARTL_Is Correction_Rewind_Report". Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: @gms0ulman: Thx. In the post I missed the closing tag. but in the original xml file it was there. Just revisited the whole ps code and found that split function used to split the value with space as the delimiter.Hence was getting that partial value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is because of the closure tag which seems missing. I don't know that is a typo or not. But When I kept it there and trying to read the content as XML parsing , I am able to retrieve it.

Could you try this:

```
<OpsConfig>
    <Tenant>mytenant_az1</Tenant>
    <Client>XYZ</Client>
    <ReviewID>a123456</ReviewID>
    <ReferenceID>ARTL_Is Correction_Rewind_Report</ReferenceID>
</OpsConfig>
```

I am in PS version 4 just FYI. Please check the PS version also

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Get-Content, you can just call on the variable to get its node.

```
[Xml]$ConfXml = Get-Content ".\config.xml"
$RefIds = $ConfXml.OpsConfig.ReferenceID
Write "$RefIds"
```

If your concern is multiple Reference IDs, you can parse them with a `ForEach`

```
ForEach ($i in $ConfXml.OpsConfig.ReferenceID) { Do stuff with $i }
```

Alternatively,

```
ForEach ($i in $ConfXml.OpsConfig) { Do stuff with $i.ReferenceID }
```

With this method, the xml attribute in the variable is just a string and shouldn't care about spaces.